# g++ why don't you have to link iostream binaries but for pthread you do?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dynamic-linking

If you have a very basic C++ program that only uses the 'cout' object, you can include iostream in the source file and then when  you compile it you don't have to link any external libraries. In other words, you can simply run

`g++ main.cpp -c`

`g++ main.o -o program`

`./program`

When you want to use more complicated objects such as threads, not only do you include pthread, but when you link the program you have to link to a library.

`g++ main.cpp -c`

`g++ main.o -lpthread -o program`

`./program`

So my question is, why didn't I have to link any libraries to use all the iostream objects?

Comment: One is a standard library and the other is a [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (p)thread library.

Comment: BTW, the correct flag is `-pthread` for both linking and compiling. When compiling it defines `_REENTRANT` macro, when linking it links the necessary libraries.

Comment: To be clear, is your program using the standard threading library (in which case you need `-pthread` not `-lpthread`, and the answer is complicated), or is it using pthreads directly (in which case the answer is that GCC only links with the standard C++ library by default)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are linking to libraries when you link with `g++ main.o -o program`. A few libraries are auto-linked by default, and the only way to *not* link to them is to pass `-nodefaultlibs` (or equivalent). In particular, you'll find `cout` in `libstdc++`, which in turn uses `libc`. Both of those are linked by default.

If you have `ldd` installed, you can verify this by running `ldd ./program`; it will give you a list of all libraries your program has linked with, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 14):

`std::cout` is defined in GCC's own C++ standard library, which `g++` links to by default, and it only depends on standard C I/O facilities such as `FILE*` and basic file I/O, which are provided in `libc`, which `gcc` and `g++` also link to by default. So everything you need to use `std::cout` is linked to by default.

Functions such as `pthread_create` are not part of the C++ or C standard libraries, they are defined in the separate library `libpthread`. That library is **not** linked to by default by GCC, because Pthreads is not part of the language (it's defined by a different standard, POSIX, but not the language standards) and also because linking to `libpthread` unconditionally would make many C++ programs run slower, for reasons explained below.

GCC's C++ standard library uses reference counting in a number of places (e.g. in the Copy-On-Write implementation of `std::string` and in `std::shared_ptr`) and in multithreaded applications the reference count updates need to use atomic instructions. In non-multithreaded applications the atomic operations are not needed, so libstdc++ uses normal, non-atomic updates if the program is single-threaded. The way it detects whether the program multithreaded or not is by checking whether the program is linked to `libpthread` or not. So linking to `libpthread` for all programs by default would cause the library to think all programs are multithreaded, and to always use the slower atomic operations, even when the program doesn't use any threads.

So to avoid making some programs slower it is the user's responsibility to link to `libpthread` explicitly when required.

On POSIX platforms `std::thread` is a thin wrapper around Pthreads, so the same rule applies for that type as for the functions like `pthread_create`: the user must link to `libpthread` manually. That's true even though `std::thread` *is* part of the language standard, but because it's implemented on top of Pthreads and because of the performance implications described above, the user must link to it manually.

Comment: Does it mean that `std::string` reference counter updates are not inlined, since it detects the multi-threaded case at link time only?

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin, they are still inlined. They are indirected through functions which then dispatch to atomic or non-atomic implementations based on a run-time check to see if `libpthread` is linked in (by checking if `pthread_create` is a weak symbol or not). The result of that check is cached in a local static and re-used on subsequent calls.

Comment: Note that with the GCC 5 ABI, `std::string` is no longer CoW.

Answer (score 4):

when building gcc and g++ you may specify "default libraries" to link with.

In some pre-built distribution they are kind enough to do -lstdc++ for you, some distribution don't.

Comment: That's not dependent on the distribution, but on whether you're linking with `gcc` or with `g++`. I suppose it's theoretically possible for a distro to remove that distinction, but I've never heard of any distro doing that.

Comment: If you build gcc yourself, you can specify a custom default libraries and link script; which is usually useful for building cross-compiler and with libc replacement.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that someone asking why they don't need to link explicitly to the stdlib has not built GCC themselves and is using a typical setup